# Rider "No Unity editor connection" Linux

Tags: unity-game-engine, rider

I've just installed Unity 2019.4.20f1 and Rider 2020.3.2, and created a new unity project.

I set the external editor to the rider executable (in `/usr/bin/rider` in my case)
I opened the sln in rider and it installed the rider plugin.

Now with both open (and having tried opening both with the other), rider refuses to connect to unity (shown by the icon down the bottom).

It should show connected but hovering just shows the error in the title. Play button in Rider is greyed out.

I've checked the first page of google and nothing there seems to fix the issue.

Steps to reproduce:

- From the AUR, download unity-hub and rider
- Install the latest recommended Unity version from hub
- Create a project in unity hub and open
- Set the external editor in unity prefs to /usr/bin/rider
- Create and double click a script

Update: Just tried Unity 2020.2.5f1 with the same issue

Comment: Have you set up Rider as the External Editor in Preferences? And then try and double click a script from within Unity

Comment: Yeah, that's been tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Rider using the jetbrains toolbox app instead of the AUR results in a correctly working installation.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't have a C# interpreter on my Arch Linux machine. To fix it I ran `sudo pacman -S mono mono-tools msbuild`, then in Jetbrains I hit `Invalidate Caches & Restart` to fix the problem.